# jQuery $.when always fails : what is $.when looking for to determine success/failure?

Tags: ajax, jquery, http-status-codes, jquery-deferred

I need to chain a reults of 2 posts and started with the deferred sample found at: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

```
var successFunction = function (event) { alert(event.readyState);  };
var failedFunction = function (event) { alert(event.readyState); };
$.when($.ajax("/page1.php", type: 'POST'), $.ajax("/page2.php", type: 'POST'))
  .then(successFunction , failedFunction );
```

In my case, the failedFunction always fires even though the event object and chrome report the following properties:

```
readyState: 4
responseText: "OK"
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
```

same results when using the following form:

```
$.when( $.ajax("/page1.php", type: 'POST'), $.ajax("/page2.php", type: 'POST'))
   .then(successFunction)
   .fail(failFunction);
```

what is $.when looking for to determine success/failure?  How do I get $.when to fire successFunction when the readyState === 4 and status === 200?  is it looking for something else I'm not sending from the server?

Comment: Perhaps the second AJAX call is failing. Try `var failedFunction = function(a, b) { alert(b.status);};`

Answer (score 0):

jQuery looks for the following status codes when checking if the ajax request was successful

```
status >= 200 && status < 300 || status === 304
```

Anything other than that would be considered not successful.

Since you have two ajax requests i'm suspecting one of them is failing.

Try to log the responses and see which particular one is failing.

```
$.when($.ajax("/page1.php", type: 'POST'), $.ajax("/page2.php", type: 'POST')).done(function(a1,  a2){
    /* arguments are [ "success", statusText, jqXHR ] */
   console.log( a1[2] ); 
   console.log( a2[2] ); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help.  I added an error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) to each of the .ajax calls which gave me more details.  Both were returning the same error "Unexpected token O" because I was returning "OK."  Once I removed the return the problem went away.  Didn't get a chance to try the done technique but I'm sure that will be helpful in the future.